# com.tangosol.net.RequestPolicyException: No storage-enabled nodes exist for service PartitionedCache

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, oracle-coherence

**When deploying my project I get the following error. Despite the error, the project is deployed and running. But in several screens I get same error and can not use these screens.**

My web application is developed using Java JSF and WebLogic.

Can anyone please help me resolve this?

first error :

2019-11-20 12:15:50.036/16.535 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.1.0  (thread=[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', member=n/a): Loaded operational configuration from "jar:file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/coherence/lib/coherence.jar!/tangosol-coherence.xml"
2019-11-20 12:15:50.192/16.692 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.1.0  (thread=[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', member=n/a): Loaded operational overrides from "jar:file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/coherence/lib/coherence.jar!/tangosol-coherence-override-dev.xml"
2019-11-20 12:15:50.193/16.693 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.1.0  (thread=[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', member=n/a): Optional configuration override "/tangosol-coherence-override.xml" is not specified
2019-11-20 12:15:50.196/16.695 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.1.0  (thread=[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', member=n/a): Optional configuration override "cache-factory-config.xml" is not specified
2019-11-20 12:15:50.196/16.696 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.1.0  (thread=[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', member=n/a): Optional configuration override "cache-factory-builder-config.xml" is not specified
2019-11-20 12:15:50.197/16.697 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.1.0  (thread=[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', member=n/a): Optional configuration override "/custom-mbeans.xml" is not specified

**seccond error :**

DEBUG Cohrence Cache started : AplOperConfig
com.tangosol.net.RequestPolicyException: No storage-enabled nodes exist for service PartitionedCache
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.onMissingStorage(PartitionedCache.CDB:23)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.c

enter code here

omponent.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.ensureRequestTarget(PartitionedCache.CDB:75)
    at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.putAll(PartitionedCache.CDB:38)
    at com.oracle.common.collections.ConverterCollections$ConverterMap.putAll(ConverterCollections.java:1570)
    ...

Comment: There is nothing JSF related in here, other than the error eventually ending up as a FacesException. The real error is way down in the stacktrace (like you already know since you used that as a title.

Comment: So does your application use Oracle Coherence?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes how can I fix this.

Comment: No Idea, II don't use it and just corrected tags

Comment: @APC yes I am using j developer which is cointains coherence

Comment: Posting large screeds of **unformatted** Java stack traces does encourage people to read your question.

Comment: These are not erros.
The first is the cohrence log that tell you configuration files loaded. 
The secondo is another debug log row. Could you share the complete stack trace?